# how to print the contents of a hidden iframe?

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, iframe

i want to print a page which i put in an iframe but dont want the contents to be displayed in the webpage ,  but the print button doesnt work when i put the iframe to display='none'

what i did:-
i set the iframe style='none'

"name="frame1" >

```
<input type="button" onclick="frames['frame1'].print()" value="print!">
```

how can i print the contents of iframe without displaying it on the webpage or say by keeping the ifram hidden

would really appreciate any help.....

Answer (score 7):

You do a print css file, and within that file you do not have the display: none style.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/print.css" media="print" />
```

[Here's a link to media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html), thanks to Dror.

Comment: I gave +1! also here is a link to media types: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of display: none, you could try visibility: hidden and setting the width and height to 1px each.