# Printing a page without displaying it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, printing

I have a page from which the user will be able to **print**. However, the page which will get printed is not the one the user is viewing, but rather a new one I'd like to generate on the background and (possibly) only show the print dialog for it.

Just to make things clear:

1. User is on "**View.aspx**" and clicks my **Print** button (not the browser's one).
2. The **Print** button loads the content of "**Printable.aspx**" and displays a print dialog for it while the user is still on "**View.aspx**".

FYI, what I'm trying to avoid is to have the "**Printable.aspx**" open in a new window and then show its print dialog.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a combination of MEDIA tags in CSS to show/hide objects for printing.

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
@media print {
   .PrintOnly {font-size: 10pt; line-height: 120%; background: white;}
}
@media screen {
   .PrintOnly {display: none}
}
</STYLE>
```

You can make controls that are style `Display:none` on media screen, so the user only sees them when printing.

```
<DIV class="PrintOnly">
This control will only show up during printing
</DIV>
```

Any of your controls can be classed as "PrintOnly" so you only see them when printing.  You just need to have the css class defined once for "@media screen" and once for "@media print" to ensure they behave differently.

You can also bring in an entire stylesheet for print-only.

```
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="screen.css" media="screen">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

Comment: +1: This way you don't even need a second page, just a second stylesheet.  The same page will simply render differently through the printer.

Comment: I would love a working example of this. I have several controls and containers I wouldn't want to be printed, but have absolutely no idea how I would go around effectively doing so. Thanks.

Comment: What if the printable version containts elements not yet loaded on the screen version? Should I load it via something like Ajax or just load a separate page on a hidden panel, like user378806 suggested? Thanks.

Comment: @Rafael: If you don't want to mess around with IFRAMEs you can just add "<body onload="window.print();history.go(-1);">" to your "Printable.aspx" page.  It will print and then return to the previous screen.  It will work better in browsers that don't support IFRAMEs.

Answer (score 1):

When the **Print** button is clicked, add the **Printable.aspx** into a  hidden panel of **view.aspx.** 
Respond by adding javascript into the onload event of **view.aspx** & print the hidden panel with **window.print()**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying for is possible. But I could be wrong. Though the better way to approach this is to use a different css stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the page into a hidden IFrame element, then use javascript to execute the print function of that page.

But, like @carter suggested, CSS is the better approach. Why load duplicate content more than once when you can just restyle the current content?

- It's also suggested in this question to use CSS: [[how to print the contents of a hidden iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580941/how-to-print-the-contents-of-a-hidden-iframe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580941/how-to-print-the-contents-of-a-hidden-iframe)
- This is a good resource for using the CSS way of printing: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Comment: What if the data to be displayed is not loaded on the current page, and the printable version contains all its details: would be better to load the remaining content via something like ajax or just load the content on a hidden panel?